# How to add a data in Tabulator using addRow method as well as AJAX?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm utilizing Tabulator version 5.5.4 in my application. I aim to incorporate data using the `addRow` method under specific conditions, and alternatively, I want to add data through AJAX in certain scenarios.

For instance, after Tabulator has been rendered, I intend to utilize the `addRow` method to insert data. Subsequently, when a user clicks the "pull data" button, I plan to retrieve and incorporate data through an AJAX request.

Is there a method to achieve this?